# How to dynamically generate many radio groups using in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to generate lists that contains label and two radios based on data from database.

component.html code:

```
<li *ngFor="let method of testMethods">
     {{ method }}
     <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="stepResult" name={{method}} value="pass">Pass
     <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="stepResult" name={{method}} value="fail">Fail
 </li>
```

component.ts code (testMethods contains example values)

```
testMethods: string[] = ["First step", "Second step", "Third step"];
stepResult;
```

What i want to achive is list that looks like this:

- First step ()Pass ()Fail
- Second step ()Pass ()Fail
- Third step ()Pass ()Fail

My problem is when i select "Pass" for one step, all "Pasess" are selected. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding all the inputs with one variable stepResult so when change occurres all inputs are updated. You can for example make stepResult an array of values:

```
 <li *ngFor="let method of testMethods; let i = index">
     {{ method }}
     <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="stepResult[i]" name={{method}} value="pass">Pass
     <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="stepResult[i]" name={{method}} value="fail">Fail
 </li>
```

And in the component:

```
stepResult = [];
```